# Two definitions of intertwining operators and Harish-Chandra's Plancherel measure

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, p-adic-groups, unitary-representations

I guess this question is a well-known fact to experts, but I didn't find any explicit explanation in the literature.

So let $F$ be a $p$-adic field. (There're parallel definitions and results in the case of real groups.) So far I found two different types of intertwining operators related to Harish-Chandra's theory, which provides two different definitions of Harish-Chandra's Plancherel measure. I think they must provide the same Harish-Chandra $\mu$-function, but I didn't find any explicit explanation in the literature.

Concretely speaking, I followed the following two very famous papers:

**(1)** Waldspurger, La formule de Plancherel pour les groupes $p$-adiques (d'après Harish-Chandra), J. Inst. Math. Jussieu 2 (2003), no. 2, 235–333

**(2)** Shahidi, A proof of Langlands' conjecture on Plancherel measures; complementary series for p-adic groups. Ann. of Math. (2) 132 (1990), no. 2, 273–330.

**The first version** (Waldspurger's paper): let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $F$ and $P=MU,P'=MU'$ two semi-standard $F$-parabolic subgroup of $G$ (i.e., both containing a fixed maximal $F$-split torus $T$, cf. 1.1 of Waldspurger's paper) with the same Levi subgroup $M$. We fix a hyperspecial maximal compact subgroup $K\subset G$. **Here in Waldspurger's paper the Haar measure on any closed subgroup $H$ of $G$ is chosen such that $K\cap H$ has volume one.**

Let $(\sigma,V)$ be a discrete series of $M$, and $I_P^G(\sigma)$ denotes the corresponding (normalized) parabolic induction. Then the intertwining operator is defined as
$$J_{P'|P}(\sigma):I^G_P(V)\rightarrow I^G_{P'}(V),$$
$$[J_{P'|P}(\sigma)\varphi](g):=\int_{U\cap U'\backslash U'}\varphi (u'g)du'.$$
Then there exists an open set $\Xi\subset \mathfrak{P}$ in the $X(M)$-orbit of $\sigma$, such that for any $\sigma'\in\Xi$, $I^G_P(\sigma')$ is irreducible. So $J_{P|\overline{P}}\circ J_{\overline{P}|P}=j(\sigma')$ is a scalar on $\Xi$. Define the Plancherel measure to be

$$\boxed{\mu(\sigma')=\mu^G(\sigma'):=j(\sigma')^{-1}\prod_{\alpha\in\Sigma_P^{red}}\gamma(M_\alpha/M)^2.}$$

**The second version:** explained in Shahidi's paper, is used in the theory of Eisenstein series and the Langlands-Shahidi method. The setting as above, and $\nu\in\mathfrak{a}_{M,\mathbb{C}}^*$ ("generalised" Plancherel measure, for the usual one, $\nu\in\mathfrak{a}_{M}^*$ would suffice). Let $P=P_\theta$, $P'=P_{\theta'}$, $N=N_\theta$, $N'=N_{\theta'}$, $M=M_\theta$, $M'=M_{\theta'}$, etc. $\theta,\theta\subset \Delta\subset \Phi^+$ are two subsets of the positive simple roots, and the above parabolic subgroups are the corresponding standard parabolic subgroups. Suppose $\tilde{w}\in W(\theta,\theta')=\{\tilde{w}\in W(T)| \tilde{w}\theta=\theta'\}$ (so $wM_\theta w^{-1}=M_{\theta'}$.) Following Shahidi's convention, $\tilde{w}\in W(T)$ is an element of the Weyl group, with $w$ its representative.

Define $N_{\tilde{w}}:=N_0\cap (wN^- w^{-1})$ ($N^-$ the opposite unipotent radical.) Then it's known that
$$((wNw^{-1})\cap N')\backslash N'\cong N_{\tilde{w}}.$$
The intertwining operator is defined to be
\begin{align*}
    [A(\nu,\sigma,w)f](g):&=\int_{N_{\tilde{w}}}f(w^{-1}ng)dn\\
    &=\int_{(wNw^{-1})\cap N'\backslash N'}f(w^{-1}n'g)dn'
\end{align*}
$$A(\nu,\sigma,w):I(\nu,\sigma)\rightarrow I(\tilde{w}\nu,\tilde{w}\sigma).$$

The "generalised" Harish-Chandra $\gamma$-constant is
$$\gamma_{\tilde{w}}(G/P):=\int_{\overline{N_{\tilde{w}}}}\delta_P(\overline{n})d\overline{n},~(\overline{N_{\tilde{w}}}:=w^{-1}N_{\tilde{w}}w).$$

Then the definition of the Plancherel measure in this context, according to Shahidi, is
$$\boxed{A(\nu,\sigma,w)A(\tilde{w}\nu,\tilde{w}\sigma,w^{-1})=\mu(\nu,\sigma,\tilde{w})^{-1}\gamma_{\tilde{w}}(G/P)\gamma_{\tilde{w}^{-1}}(G/P')}.$$
(From this definition, it's clear that $\mu$-function is independent of the choice of the Haar measures. In this context, the measures used to define $\gamma$-constants are chosen to be the same as that of the intertwining operators, so they cancelled.)

As Shahidi mentioned, **when $\tilde{w}=\tilde{w_0}$ is the "longest" element in $W(\theta,\theta')$, the corresponding $\mu(\nu,\sigma,\tilde{w}):=\mu(\nu,\sigma)$ is the usual Harish-Chandra $\mu$-function.**

I tried to see how it works, but so far I couldn't give a clear, explicit proof that these two definitions coincide. As noted in Silberger's book Introduction to Harmonic Analysis on Reductive $p$-adic Groups,

"It's not true that $\gamma(G/M)=\prod_{\alpha\in\Sigma_P^{red}}\gamma(M_\alpha/M)$."

But these two formalisms must provide the same notion of $\mu$-function (for example, this was used already in Aubert, Anne-Marie; Plymen, Roger Plancherel measure for $GL(n,F)$ and $GL(m,D)$: explicit formulas and Bernstein decomposition. J. Number Theory 112 (2005), no. 1, 26–66. ) Can any expert give me some help?